# Change LDAP user password using PHP in windows server 2008

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to let my active directory users to change their passwords from a linked form with PHP code.
when I used ldap_modify function, it changes the mail but it never change the password, however it replied with success message.
I use this to encrypt the password:

```
  $encoded_newPassword = "{SHA}" . base64_encode( pack( "H*", sha1( $newPassword ) ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a password change, you need to follow the procedure and format described in the [documentation for the `unicodePwd` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2). You have to do two operations in the same request:

- A remove operation that includes the old password, and
- An add operation that includes the new password

And both passwords have to be in a specific format.

To do this in PHP, you use `ldap_modify_batch`. In the documentation for `ldap_modify_batch` [there is an example of how to do a password change](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-modify-batch.php#example-4366):

```
function adifyPw($pw)
{
    return iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE", '"' . $pw . '"');
}

$dn = "cn=Jack Smith-Jones,ou=Wizards,dc=ad,dc=example,dc=com";
$modifs = [
    [
        "attrib"  => "unicodePwd",
        "modtype" => LDAP_MODIFY_BATCH_REMOVE,
        "values"  => [adifyPw("Tr0ub4dor&3")],
    ],
    [
        "attrib"  => "unicodePwd",
        "modtype" => LDAP_MODIFY_BATCH_ADD,
        "values"  => [adifyPw("correct horse battery staple")],
    ],
];
ldap_modify_batch($connection, $dn, $modifs);
```

Comment: Thanks for your rebly, but when I use unicodePwd I get this error message ` 53 - Server is unwilling to perform `

Comment: @Aalaamohammad I should have mentioned that the other requirement is that you are connected using encryption. So that means using LDAPS. That means using `ldaps://` in `ldap_connect`. That also depends on the SSL certificate from the server being trusted.

Comment: thank you for your time and your answer it helped me a lot.